# Rails 5 undefined method `before_filter' in include. Mobylette

Tags: passenger, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting the following error when running rails s
RoR 5.1.5 passenger standalone

> ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method 'before_filter' for
>   ApplicationController:Class Did you mean?  before_action):
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4:in 'include'
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4:in
>   `'
>   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in ''
>   app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:1:in ''
>   ^CExitingStopping web server...

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_action :require_login
include Mobylette::RespondToMobileRequests
private
    def not_authenticated
      redirect_to login_path, alert: "Please login first"
    end
end
```

Comment: have you checked welcome_controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fixed mobylette load error](https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette/pull/53/files#diff-9f99796b5fe9f9971c8e8df2a2ce7414R36)

This pull request fixes the error, but has not been pulled.